# Repair increment data in array (js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to correct the incremented value in the data I received. It looks more or less like this:

```
const data = [1,2,4,5,6,7];
const correctResult = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

What I would like to get is rightly incremented values + 1 but so as to preserve the possible indexes.

I wrote such a function but it is not efficient:

```js
let array = [1,2,4,5,6,7];
array.map((item, index, array) => {
  if (item === array[index + 1] - 1) {
    return;
  }

  array[index + 1] = array[index + 1] - 1;
});

console.log(array)
```

The programming code is javascript. I would like to write a good code to be a good model for me.

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem. Why is the data you receive off?

Comment: Also never use a map when you need a forEach. Waste of an array

Comment: I delete one of the values via sql. what I can get is the rest of the data. I would like to fix it and update it.

Comment: this is the server code. @mplungjan

Comment: @mplungjan I added tag.

Comment: no clue why you would do this and what the origin of this problem is

Comment: We need more code. Show where and why you delete the sql values

Comment: `const correctResult = data.map((item, index) => (item - 1 !== index) ? --item  : item);`

Comment: Looking at the expected result, you want to "re-index" the array.
Can you give an example of the expected result for [1, 4, 7, 8, 12]? My guess is: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Is it correct?

Comment: @PatriceThimothee yes, its correctly.

Comment: Thank you, @jsobjectkeys2. I have deleted my post. I failed to see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is the exact answer you seek, but you can try this too

```js
const data = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const correctResult =  data.map((item, index) => {
if (item - 1 !== index) {
  return  --item;
}
else {
  return item;
}
});
console.log(correctResult);
```

Comment: WHY are you using Array.map??? Waste of an array! Or you are doing it wrong. use map correctly or use a forEach or reduce or for loop

Comment: `const correctResult = data.map((item, index) => (item - 1 !== index) ? --item  : item);`